# Add values in different rows

Tags: awk

I have this table:

[image]

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sd2=`iostat -xz | awk '/sd2/ {print $8}'`

sd3=`iostat -xz | awk '/sd3/ {print $8}'`

delta=$sd2-$sd3

echo "Message: Hard Drive Service Time Delta"

echo "Data:"

printf $delta
```

The output of script is: `0.4-0.4`

Question: What do I need to do to get the output: 0

Tia!

Comment: you should try `bc` or `awk`

Comment: You have the wrong approach (running the same command and parsing its output multiple times) and so have accepted the wrong answer as it helps you implement that wrong approach. If you post some textual sample input instead of the image then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
delta=$(bc <<< "$sd2-$sd3")
```

or

```
delta=$(echo $sd2 $sd3 |awk '{print $1-$2}')
```

Comment: Both works. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is something like this:

```
iostat -xz | awk '
{ svc_t[$1] = $8 }
END {
    delta = svc_t["sd2"] - svc_t["sd3"]
    print "Message: Hard Drive Service Time Delta"
    print "Data:"
    print delta
}'
```

It's untested since you didn't provide input we could test against nor the exact expected output but it'll be close if not exactly right.